# PHP file is not running in XAMPP server

Tags: php, server, xampp, localhost

[I am running the php file in localhost and the browser (chrome) is showing the blank page then i inspect the code and found the php code or part is commented automatically. What can I do I am novice so help me with this please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwSTt.png)I am trying to run a  single php file with  code `<? echo "as"; ?>` but xampp server is showing blank page. Xampp server only loads index.php file. I am accessing or trying to run other php file on localhost server but it always shows blank page.

Comment: Please do not add links to images of code. Questions should be self contained. Put your code in code blocks withing the question. Please see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write PHP tags correctly

```
<?php echo "hello "; ?>
```

if it does not solve the problem please share xampp log with us and be sure there is no any error durring starting.

Comment: when I am clicking on php(php_error_log) in logs in xampp control the following dialog box is appearing with empty notepad... "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: php programming language starts with <?php and closes with ?> if you see a blank page porbably it cannot display your message please be sure that you write correctly

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying with that code. These are called short_open_tags in php. And these returning you blank page, because these need to enable in php.ini file. Go to your php.ini file change below command

short_open_tags = Off

To

short_open_tags = On

Restart your xampp server. Now your code will run.